# How can I update particular fields of model with validation in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is an AcviteRecord Model named `User` like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

  validates :plain_password, :presence => true, :confirmation => true
  validates :plain_password_confirmation, :presence => true
  #...other codes
end
```

It requires that the update of name and email and the update of password are separated.

When only update name and password, using `update` or `update_attributes` will cause password validation which is not needed. But using `update_attribute` will save name and email without validation.

Are there any ways to update particular fields of model with validation without causing the other fields' validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try, might help

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, :uniqueness => true

  validates :plain_password, length: { in: 4..255, allow_nil: true }, confirmation: true
  validates :plain_password_confirmation, presence: true, if: -> (user){ user.plain_password.present? }

  # ......
  # ......
end
```

Apart from this you should reconsider about saving plain_password ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your validations to only run on create. Requiring confirmation ensures changes on edit are applied.

```
validates :plain_password,
          confirmation: true,
          presence: {
            on: :create },
          length: {
            minimum: 8,
            allow_blank: true }

validates :plain_password_confirmation,
          presence: {
            on: :create }
```

I am assuming you are hashing your passwords, so this would accompany code similar to:

```
attr_accessor :plain_password

before_save :prepare_password

def encrypted_password( bcrypt_computational_cost = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10)
  BCrypt::Password.create plain_password, cost: bcrypt_computational_cost
end

private #===========================================================================================================


# Sets this users password hash to the encrypted password, if the password is not blank.
def prepare_password
  self.password_hash = encrypted_password if plain_password.present?
end
```

A better way to handle this is to not include the fields in the rest of the edit form, but rather provide a link to "Change my password". This link would direct to a new form (perhaps in a modal window) which will require the new password, confirmation of the new password, and the old password, to prevent [account hijacking](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#account-hijacking).

Comment: @Jerry Potentially, but this is usually handled in the password hashing logic. I updated the answer to reflect this. Hopefully you are not storing your plaintext passwords in the database...

Comment: The plain_password and plain_password_confirmation are both virtual attributes and won't be stored in database. There's also hashing logic in my codes, but I didn't figure out the presence checking can be handled in hashing logic. And if it can't be handled like this, does it mean the plain_password's `presence: {on: :create}` can be removed from the `validates` directive?

Comment: @Brad_Werth And when `plain_password` is not presented, should there be an error message appended to `errors[:plain_password]` in hashing logic?

Comment: @Jerry Good, this assumes virtual attributes - best way to do it. If you just don't save the hash, in your existing method, when the password is blank, you should be good to go. The check for presence on create ensures a new user cannot be created with a blank password, so I would recommend keeping that bit in there.

Comment: There will be an error if the password or confirmation is blank during create, or if during an edit the password or confirmation field is filled in and doesn't match. The assumption being that if they don't enter anything during an edit, it just stays the same.

Comment: You might seriously consider breaking the password modification out, and requiring the original password to change it. It is more secure, and more intuitive in the UI.

Comment: I broke it out, and made requirement of original password :) But when update other fields like name and email, the password is empty just like the users enter nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use [has_secure_password](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) The password presence is only validated on creation.

Comment: This has the side-effect of limiting hashed passwords to 72 characters.

Comment: I do not really understand your question. Do you think 72 characters are not enough?

Comment: I think artificially imposing a low limit on a hashed password unnecessarily impacts the security of the application, with no upside. Whether it is enough... Maybe for some sites it is sufficient, but my email and banking passwords are certainly longer than that...